# Find the prime DATE

Tags: sas

2019-05-23 is a normal but great day. It is normal because there is nothing big happen to me, it is also very great since I find this story in my social network.

20190523 is a prime.
0190523 is a prime.(let's just allow this leading zero)
190523 is a prime.
...
23 is a prime.
3 is a prime.

So my question is : Are there any other date behaves the same properties?
And what I want is a very nice method so let's limit the search range as 2019-05-23 to 9999-12-31.

Hope you can enjoy this puzzle.

Comment: Is it a fun question, or you actually need to implement it for some code?

Comment: @Rhythm That is not so serious, just hope you can have fun with SAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there was just a discussion about how to generate prime numbers using Sieve of Eratosthenes method.  So we can first run that and then loop over the dates and convert them into the series of numbers and check if they are primes.

```
data prime_dates ;
  array sieve[99991231] _temporary_ ;
  sieve[1]=1;
  do i=2 to int(sqrt(hbound(sieve)));
    if sieve[i]=. then do j=i**2 by i to hbound(sieve);
      sieve[j]=1;
    end;
  end;
  do date='23may2019'd to '31DEC9999'd ;
    string=put(date,yymmddn8.);
    prime=1;
    do pos=1 to 8 while(prime);
      prime=.=sieve[input(substr(string,pos),8.)];
    end;
    if prime then output;
  end;
  stop;
  drop i j pos prime;
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;
```

This results in 409 similar date.  The next is in August of this year.  Here are the first 10.

```
Obs          date     string

  1    2019-05-23    20190523
  2    2019-08-23    20190823
  3    2030-03-17    20300317
  4    2036-03-17    20360317
  5    2040-03-07    20400307
  6    2040-08-23    20400823
  7    2048-01-07    20480107
  8    2060-03-17    20600317
  9    2066-06-17    20660617
 10    2070-01-03    20700103
```

Note there is no need to add index 0 to the sieve since the 10th, 20th and 30th day of the month will fail at the 2 digit check as being not prime so index of 0 is never attempted.

I counted 1 as NOT prime.  If you count 1 as prime then you get an additional 185 dates, first one being the first day of year 2060.

Comment: Nice work. May I ask how does this piece of code works:  `do i=2 to int(sqrt(hbound(sieve)));
    if sieve[i]=. then do j=i**2 by i to hbound(sieve);
      sieve[j]=1;
    end;
  end;`

Comment: For any number that has not already been crossed off (has a missing value still) the list it crosses out numbers that are multiples of that number.  To save a little time it starts the inner loop at the number squared because smaller multiples would have already been crossed out by the smaller prime factors.  For the same reason there is no need for the main loop to extend beyond the square root of the maximum number.